# What's the difference between :: and ::: in Scala

Tags: scala

```
val list1 = List(1,2)
val list2 = List(3,4)
```

then

```
list1::list2 returns:

List[Any] = List(List(1, 2), 3, 4)

list1:::list2 returns:

List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I saw the book writes that when use `::` it also results `List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)`. My Scala version is 2.9.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

`::` prepends a single item whereas `:::` prepends a complete list. So, if you put a `List` in front of `::` it is taken as one item, which results in a nested structure.

Comment: For performance reason, is there difference between `::` and `:::` ?

Comment: Performance should be `O(n)` with `n` being the number of elements to prepend.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this operation an append rather than a prepend?

Comment: an example would make it much easier to understand

Comment: @JanacMeena, this operation is a prepend, [List](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) is immutable-singly-linked: after concatenation the a new head is prepended, referencing the existing list directly: it becomes Aliased/shared in memory. It is very cpu/memory efficient for certain patterns of code. This works due to a subtle thing with infix operators: any ending in ':' are right-associative - they are actually defined as a method on the class to their RIGHT not their left. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15384749/932359)

Answer (score 32):

In general:

- `::` - adds an element at the beginning of a list and returns a list with the added element
- `:::` - concatenates two lists and returns the concatenated list

For example:

```
1 :: List(2, 3)             will return     List(1, 2, 3)
List(1, 2) ::: List(3, 4)   will return     List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

In your specific question, using `::` will result in list in a list (*nested list*) so I believe you prefer to use `:::`.

> Reference: [class List int the official site](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.5.1/scala/List.html#%3A%3A%28B%29)

Comment: So, same as `++`?