# How to make a right-associative infix operator?

Tags: scala, associative, infix-notation

I have an associative operation `>>`. The problem is that its cost linearly depends on the size of its left operand. So an expression formed by a sequence of `n` applications of `>>` like

```
a >> a >> a >> a >> a >> ... >> a
```

it has quadratic cost in terms of `n`, because by default infix operators are [left-associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property). How to make it right-associative so that the cost of such an expression is kept linear in terms of `n`?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I found a solution. Scala [reference](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#prefix-infix-and-postfix-operations) says in section *6.12.3 Infix Operations*:

> The *associativity* of an operator is determined by the operator’s last character. Operators
>   ending in a colon ‘:’ are right-associative. All other operators are left-associative.

Therefore it was enough to rename `>>` to `>>:`.

It took me some time to realize that while `a >> b` is desugared into `a.>>(b)`, `a >>: b` is desugared into `b.>>:(a)`. So I had to define `>>:` as

```
def >>:(x: T): T = x >> this
```