# Idiomatic way to prepend list to another list in Scala

Tags: scala

Sorry for the novice question, but I can't find the shorthand for this in Scala.

```
val s1 = List(8, 9, 10)
val s2 = List(7, 6, 5)
val s12 = s2.foldLeft(s1)((acc, x) => x :: acc)
assert(s12 === List(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

Which operator should I use to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could reverse the 2nd list and prepend the result to the 1st list

```
val s12 = s2.reverse ::: s1
```

For additional documentation of the methods available refer to the [`scala.collection.immutable.List` APIdocs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List)

e.g. `:::`

> Adds the elements of a given list in front of this list.

By the way `:::` used like this (infix notation - without dot) is [right-associative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15384749/3041008) (it means the method will be called on the right object - `s1` in this case).
Moreover, when calling `:::` with dot notation, it will be called on the object left of the dot, so in this case `s2.reverse.:::(s1)` will result in `List(8, 9, 10, 5, 6, 7)`

Comment: From what I understand that'd tad inefficient. I found `xs reverse_::: ys` which is "more efficient" according to the API docs but it sort of looks ugly..

Comment: @BasilTomato If you're talking about a small and bounded number of items, I'd choose aesthetics over performance every time. If it's a large or unbounded number of items and you're really worried about performance, you can choose a more sophisticated data structure like a `Vector` and use its `reverseIterator` to access each item in the order you want.

Comment: @BasilTomato `xs reverse_::: ys` looks interesting. Where is the API docs for it?

Comment: @acjay: I guess, it just feels wrong to effectively reverse it twice.

Comment: @mucaho: It's here -> http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List

Comment: @BasilTomato that's actually nice, I suggest you answer your own question with that variant too

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, it can be written this way:

```
s2 reverse_::: s1
```

Which is more efficient than `s2.reverse ::: s1` (this is also pointed out in the API doc).

It can also be written in this horrible way:

```
(s1 /: s2)(_.::(_))
```

On second thought, maybe `s2.foldLeft(s1)((acc, x) => x :: acc)` isn't that bad after all.