# Calling lists concatenation in Scala

Tags: scala, list

Can someone explain what is going on with

```
scala> List(1,2).:::(List(3,4))
res15: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 1, 2)

scala> List(1,2) ::: List(3,4)
res16: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

How can the method call results differ while they should be the same method call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of `List(1,2).:::(List(3,4))` you call `:::` method directly on object `List(1,2)`. According to the docs:

> @param **prefix**  The list elements to prepend.

So you get: `res15: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 1, 2)`

When you do not use `.` (dot) notation `:::` behaves as **right associative** operation according to the docs:

> @usecase def :::(prefix: List[A]): List[A]
>      @inheritdoc
>
> Example:
>       {{{List(1, 2) ::: List(3, 4) = List(3, 4).:::(List(1, 2)) = List(1, 2, 3, 4)}}}

That means that in the case of `List(1,2) ::: List(3,4)` method `:::` is being called on object `List(3,4)`.

**Right associative operation** means basically the following:

`xs ::: ys ::: zs` is interpreted as `xs ::: (ys ::: zs)`

Section [16.6](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/working-with-lists.html) describes the same as example.

Comment: Actually found some pretty good discussions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162924/what-good-are-right-associative-methods-in-scala and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384744/how-to-make-a-right-associative-infix-operator basically if the colon is the last element of the method name, it is right associative. So for example def mymethod:(param: MyClass) starts a right-associative method named 'mymethod:', which calls on the parameter object.

Comment: Thanks for sharing